# Prevent word wrap in GUI text

Tags: matlab, text, matlab-guide, word-wrap

I have a MATLAB GUI that allows a user to load a configuration file. I then want the filename to be displayed in a static text field. My problem is that the string is too long for my text field and wraps around. I want the text to display as much of the string as it can without wrapping, prioritizing the end of the string.

For example, if I have a filename `'C:\folders\more\folders\thisismylongfilename.txt'`, I am currently seeing

```
C:\folders\more\folders\thisism
              ylongfilename.txt
```

If I use an edit text rather than a static text, I see `C:\folders\more\folders\thisism`

I would like my text field to display `olders\thisismylongfilename.txt`, or maybe `...ers\thisismylongfilename.txt`. The missing portion can either be "displayed" but outside the visible box, or something I can remove before displaying. I would just need to know how much of the string to remove.

How can I properly display my long string in a fixed width text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be read the length of your textbox and shorten the string before you display it.

```
myString = 'path/to/file/file.txt';

set(handles.textbox,'Units', 'Characters'); %set units to characters for convenience
pos = get(handles.textbox,'Position'); %get the position info
maxLength = floor(pos(3)); %extract the length of the box 
if length(myString) > maxLength % cut beginning if string is too long 
    newStart = length(myString) - maxLength + 1;
    displayString = myString(newStart:end);
else
    displayString = myString;
end

set(handles.textbox,'String', displayString);
```

Comment: For some reason my `floor(pos(3))` is not quite enough. It gives me a value of 44, but only 41 characters fit. When I load in the full 53-ch string, the Extent is actually 58. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: In my test I used a fontsize of 8, using a larger fontsize or a different font could cause that. You could probably just use a multiplier like `0.9` to make it a bit shorter.

Comment: I am using a fontsize of 8 as well, in MS SansSerif

Comment: That's a units issue then, as far as I can tell... I'm using 2015b atm, that could also have an impact.

Comment: My units are characters, and fontunits are points. The only difference I'm seeing is that I'm running 2016a.